# How to implement Micrometer metrics as a dynamic map

Tags: java, amazon-cloudwatch, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I have a use case where we want to capture metrics for a certain category of data. The different entries in the category is dynamic, and cannot be hardcoded. How would we define such metrics in Micrometer? I have worked with DistributionSummary, Gauge etc. but it takes measurement for only a single metric.

The example is like this: Suppose if there is a course website (like Udemy, Coursera) where we monitor details for which person attends a course. The table is like this:

```
| Name    | Country    | Course   | Duration | Active |
| ABC     | USA        | AWS 101  | 1.5      | true   |
| XYZ     | IND        | JPN 101  | 0.5      | false  |
```

I want to plot a metric of number of people active per country to show it on CloudWatch or any other service. Something like:

```
Map<String,AtomicInteger> numberOfActiveUsersPerCountry;
....
....
public void incrementActiveUsersPerCountry(String country) {
    if(numberOfActiveUsersPerCountry.containsKey(country) {
         //increment existing count
    } else {
         //add the new country
    }
```

This should be accessible via Micrometer and be accessible in Cloudwatch/ELK etc.

Comment: It looks like you're wanting a `Tag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `counter` with the tag of the country is exactly what you want:

```
meterReg.counter("users.active", Tags.of("counter", country)).increment()
```

A counter lets you calculate the rate it is increasing and the total within a timeframe. The tag on that counter mean it creates the counter by country to allow aggregation/querying on that tag.